# how to give get and set for autoincrement field in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7

I'm Developing Database Application in wp7 using sqlite in which i set sno as autoincrement primarykey.In That Application i use helper utility and another class where i can use get and set property.if i use get and set property for sno it always set to 0 which throws exception when i inserted the record for second time as **Constraint Failed**.If I remove the Sno Property from the class its working fine,but i was not able display the sno in listbox as it is not present in the class and if i only use the get property The exception was thrown as

> Error 2 'Sample.Data.Case.SNo.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors.

i don't know how to solve this problem.please provide me a solution

Comment: of course you could have posted your code, cause i dont have telekinesis to see where your problem comes from.

Comment: here is the class where i declared get and set property for the fields in table[link](http://pastebin.com/4BrKrSLF). And what i want is need to get the assigning the autoincrement in sno

Answer (score 0):

To get the [SQLite autoincrement value](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) in the record, you must insert the column as `NULL`, which corresponds to [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) in C#.

Comment: But When i Insert a value,the invalidCastException occurs at at the line **SNo = Convert.ToInt32(DBNull.Value)**.I Was Declared SNo as int? data type

Comment: Without assigning a value to Sno makes a record to be inserted sucessfully,but while a retrieving a value it throws an exception **NotSupportedException was Unhandled.Don't know how to read System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]**